# Delta copy using Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, file-io

I'm using Visual Basic to create a program and one part of the program is to copy huge files from a remote server that is connected slowly. So I want to transfer as littleas possible.

I thought to use something like a delta copy (you know it from Backup software and/or version control systems like SVN). Then I just have to copy these parts of a file that have been changed since the last copy.

Is there any possibility to execute something  like this using the Visual Basic programming language?

Comment: Possibly, depending on the nature of the file, but not with a library. You have to implement it yourself using low level io.

Comment: See these: [Compare the contents of two directories in Visual Basic .NET](http://www.vb-helper.com/howto_net_compare_directories.html) and [Directory Comparer - A recursive tool to compare 2 folders](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/312484/Directory-Comparer-A-recursive-tool-to-compare-2-f). Found by googling.

Comment: It depends what access you have to the server, if its a high level protocol like ftp no, if you can execute code on the server or have access with a protocol like nfs or ssh then yes.